# How to get chrome browser network laps logs in karate UI automation

Tags: oauth-2.0, karate, browser-testing, karate-call-single

As part of Oath 2.0 client credential  (response type code and ,microsoft SSO) automatio , I need to retreive token from the browser logs (from n/w tabs or response headers) that bearer token can be used in the subsequent API request

n

I am using  Brower logs in selenium
LogEntries les = browser.manage().logs().get(LogType.PERFORMANCE);

Looking for similar options in karate UI

Answer (score 0):

If it is just an API call, just make it using Karate's API capabilities. That should be much easier than fiddling with logs. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+oauth

Your question is not clear, so I can't help more than this.

There is an improvement to the `develop` branch that may be of interest: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2361