# how to pass MFA token on Karate headers

Tags: karate

how do i setup MFA auto generate authorization toke on karate example: headers : * headers{Content-Type:'application/Json, Authorization: {{MFA}}'}?
this MFA will auto generate when any new user login.

can't figure out, without this Auth token all the request will failed

Comment: please refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76896629/143475